# Cannot Pass values from plain HTML to ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, html

I'm using an html file like below (tv.html):

```
<form action="myaspx.aspx?appid=5018" method="post" id="formSubscription" name="formSubscription">
<input type="checkbox" id="chckIsConfirm" name="chckIsConfirm"/> I Confirm
            <input type="submit" value="Ok" />
</form>
```

And trying to get it from "myaspx.aspx". And the code behind is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
               var r = HttpContext.Current.Request["chckIsConfirm"];
                 //Or
                NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form;
               //Or
              var a = Request.Form.AllKeys;
            }
}
```

But I cannot pass the value of "chckIsConfirm". All keys comes empty.. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: Only when I check the checkbox it comes as "ON" other times just NULL.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the default behavior for checkboxes in most browsers.  If it's not checked the browser will not send it with the request.  As a workaround add a hidden field that has the same name as the checkbox and value "0", "OFF", "FALSE" or whatever you want the "unchecked" value to be.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `runat="server"`

**aspx**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chckIsConfirm" runat="server" name="chckIsConfirm"/>
```

**cs**

```
var checked= chckIsConfirm.Checked;
```

Comment: `runt="server"` is not necessary to simply post to an ASPX page from a non-aspx page.

Comment: No I know that. But it is much easier to get the value if you have.

Comment: I guess "easier" would depend on the actual usage scenario (same/different servers etc.)

Comment: Yeah that depends on the scenario right. But using a hidden filed for a work around instead of having runat="server". Is that a god solution?

Comment: Of course it is in this situation (and is fairly common).  If I have an .html page (which he indicated he did) just adding `runat="server"` won't really do anything.  You would first have to convert the entire page to regular ASP.NET webform and then adding `runat="server"` would have an effect.

Comment: To add - using the hidden field is so common, in fact, that it's adopted as default behavior in many frameworks, including Zend Framework (for PHP) and ASP.NET MVC

Comment: Ok. Sorry about that. Did not see that the OP had a HTML page. Your point is correct. That will not have any effect if the html page if is not converted to a aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

From your posted code, you are checking them only on first request, but when you click the button it is a postback so you are skiping the read of values